# How far can the sound of a sonic boom travel?

Tags: weather, fluid-dynamics, extreme-weather, sonic-boom

Are there conditions or distances from the plane to cloud to the observer in which a sonic boom from a plane is muted?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I removed the comments about lightning from your question, because they seem to have nothing to do with sonic booms from aircraft. If I got it wrong, you can edit the question again or roll back my changes. You might also like to look at [the questions we already have on sonic booms](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aaviation.stackexchange.com+Sonic+boom&oq=site&aqs=chrome.1.69i59l3j69i57j69i65.1676j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#sbfbu=1&pi=site:aviation.stackexchange.com%20Sonic%20boom) to see if they help.

Comment: My theory is the clouds containing water create a denser surface in which sound echoes or reflects off. Heat lightning or cloud lightning occurs higher off the cloud and above the base of the cloud. With the water being denser below the lightning or sonic boom sound is reflected up where ground lightning is acoustically contained between the cloud base and ground. I believe planes traveling at the right distance from the tops of clouds can reflect more sonic boom away from the ground.